# Import to another .py file

Tags: python

```
def write_to_file(string_in):
    print("write_to_file")
    split_string1 = string_in.split(',') 
    f = open("test.txt", "wt")
    for item in split_string1:
        f.write("item = {} \n".format(item.lstrip(' ')))

    f.close()

def check_in_file(string_in):
    code = input("Please enter your code")
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:    
        for line in f:
            if code in line:     
                print('success')
                break
        else:
            print('please try again')
        


def add_code(string_in):
    print("add_to_file")
    with open('test.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write("item = {} \n".format(string_in))



def delete_file(string_in):
    print("deleted_from_file")
    with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
        d = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for i in d:
            for item in string_in.split(','):
                if i.strip("\n") != "item = " + item.lstrip(' ') + " ":
                    f.write(i)
                    f.truncate()  


class keypad:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
```

#below is the text file

```
    string1 = "1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008"
    write_to_file(string1)
    add_code("1009 \nitem = 1010 \nitem = 1011")
    delete_file("1004")
    check_in_file('item = {}')
```

Right now i have anther .py file with the following (poop is my .py file):
from poop import *
write_to_file, add_code, check_in_file, delete_file, keypad

it shows nothing on the "extra.py" file besides what is above this line, is it supposed to import all my methods directly to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify any information about your files, or your file system, I will show you an example below, how you can import python code into another.

File1.py

```
import file2

file2.write_to_file("random string")
```

or

File1.py

```
from file2 import *

write_to_file("random string")
```

File2.py

```
def write_to_file(string):
    print(string)
```

Edit

"I am trying to call the methods from the first code in the "class: keypad" to the second .py file (the write_to_file, etc.. methods)"

You should import everything from second.py

```
from second import *
```

Put this into your first.py, or whatever. Now you can use those functions in second.py freely.

[check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-module-python/)

Comment: I am trying to call the methods from the first code in the "class: keypad" to the second .py file (the write_to_file, etc.. methods)